# Dialogflow and C#. How do I get a response from an agent?

Tags: c#, request, response, bots, dialogflow-es

I want to write an app in C# where I can send a message to my bot and get a response. How to send a request and get a response from the Dialogflow bot?
Please, If you know help me)
Thanks

Comment: did you even try anything so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written simple bots for Dialogflow / Google Home in C# using the following Nuget package.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2

Docs: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/dialogflow/v2/csharp/latest/

You can use the webhookrequest and webhookresponse classes to send and recieve information from Dialogflow.

It can be a bit more trouble than the NodeJs version, but with some work it is possible.

Comment: Thank you!!!! Do you have some code example? If you don’t have, never mind) Thank you!